# Paypal Adaptive Api payment error failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, paypal

I am using adaptive url like

```
$url = trim("https://svcs.".$sandbox."paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");
```

I am getting this error Message: ||**php error message** = `fopen(https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay):` failed to open stream: **HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request** ||

Comment: where i use urlencode() function. i get new error :- fopen(https%3A%2F%2Fsvcs.sandbox.paypal.com%2FAdaptivePayments%2FPay): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: urlencode("https://svcs.".$sandbox."paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `urlencode()`:

```
$url = urlencode("https://svcs.".$sandbox."paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");
```

Comment: same error fopen(https%3A%2F%2Fsvcs.sandbox.paypal.com%2FAdaptivePayments%2FPay): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: $params = array("http" => array( 
    "method" => "POST",
    "content" => $body_data,
    "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
         "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
         "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
         "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
         "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
         "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n".
         "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: " . $PROXY_HOST . "\r\n"
    ));

Comment: @ramesh: try it with file_get_contents('https://svc'.$sandbox.'paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay');

Comment: i m using $ctx = stream_context_create($params); then $response = stream_get_contents($fp);